# How to handle if number of div changes in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

So I have a div which contains 4 child divs.
The div look like this:

```
    <div class="foo">
     <div class="bar">
         <div>
           <span class="a">1</span>
           <span class="b">2</span>
           <span class="c">3</span> 
         </div> 
    </div>
     <div class="bar">
         <div>
           <span class="a">4</span>
           <span class="b">5</span>
           <span class="c">6</span> 
         </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
         <div>
           <span class="a">7</span>
           <span class="b">8</span>
           <span class="c">9</span> 
         </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
         <div>
           <span class="a">10</span>
           <span class="b">11</span>
           <span class="c">12</span>  
         </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
```

I am able to **scrape** data from the website if the page has all the four divs using index 0,1,2,3. However  certain page do not have all 4 divs and only has 3 divs and since I am fetching value using index my code breaks.
Is there a way to set value empty if the index of data is not present.Let's say 4th div is not present so just print empty.

Comment: Are these divs containing page Pagination?

Comment: Do you have a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `try` and `except`, so for example:

```
try:
  x = value_div4
except:
  x = ''
```

Comment: can you provide an example as well please